# Android Studio Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/BCKEY.DSA

Tags: android, android-studio

My code builds fine, but when I try to run it in debug, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/BCKEY.DSA
        File1: D:\Android\AndroidStudio\gradle\m2repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.48\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar
        File2: C:\Users\beili\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.48\960dea7c9181ba0b17e8bab0c06a43f0a5f04e65\bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: OMG,I 'll try to download another version Android Studio.this problem repeatedly appears。   Thank for all

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your build.gradle inside the android section like

```
android{
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
    exclude 'AUTHORS'
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK AUTHORS
 File1: D:\Android\AndroidStudio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\external\lombok\lombok-ast\0.2.3\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar
 File2: D:\Android\AndroidStudio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\external\lombok\lombok-ast\0.2.3\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar

Comment: @binding please check the edit, you just need to add as a new exclude the word after APK in the error output.

Comment: @euryp you can explain for us why this error happens ?!

Comment: It happens because more than one of your dependencies has those files and clashes when gradle tries to merge it.