# Android Studio error: Duplicate files copied in APK AUTHORS

Tags: android, gradle

I get an error in building my app. 
How can I instruct Android Studio not to copy duplicates?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevelopmentDebug'     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK AUTHORS
File1: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar
File2: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar
```

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' 
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "us.martypants.wwt"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

signingConfigs {
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        pseudoLocalesEnabled true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

      dexOptions {
       maxProcessCount 2
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
wearApp project(':wear')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:24.2.1'

// REST
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
// Rx
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.5.0'
compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.5.0'
compile 'com.minimize.android:rxrecycler-adapter:1.2.1'
compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
// Dagger 2
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
// Event bus
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
// Logging
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
}
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787399/android-studio-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-bckey-dsa. Try excluding it with `packagingOptions`.

Comment: tried multiple variations - all to no avail

Comment: What was the last dependency you added before you ran into this issue? This is a compilation issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution?